# how to get the attribute of two elements that has the same event listener

Tags: jquery

My title might not really express what i'm trying to achieve, below is code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm-delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Confirm Delete</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>You are about to delete an item.</p>
                <p>Do you want to proceed?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-ok">Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class='col-md-1 cart_action pull_right' title='delete item'>
   <i data-toggle='modal' data-target='#confirm-delete' class='glyphicon 
     glyphicon-trash deletecart' data-id=".$carts[$key]['id']." data-
     itemNo=".$carts[$key]['item_number'].">
   </i>
</div>

     function deletecart(id,item_no){
     var url = '{$url}'+'?itemNumber='+item_no+'&mode=remove&status=';
       $.ajax({
                    url: '{$deletecartUrl}',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {id: id},
        success: function (data) {  
                    if(data === 'success'){
                      window.location= url+data;
                  }else{
                      window.location= url+data;
                 }
               },
            error: function(jqXHR, errMsg) {
             // handle error
                console.log(errMsg);
            }
        });
   }


$('#confirm-delete').on('click','.btn-ok', '.deletecart', function(e) {
        var modalDiv = $(e.delegateTarget);
        id =  $(this).attr('data-id');
        item_no = $(this).attr('data-itemNo');
                    console.log(id); 
                    console.log(item_no); return;
        //deletecart(id,item_no);
        modalDiv.addClass('loading');
        setTimeout(function() {
            modalDiv.modal('hide').removeClass('loading');
        }, 1000)
    });
```

On click of the ok button in the modal i want to get the value of the data-id and data-itemNo so i can send through ajax, I was able to do this without using the BS modal using the below code

```
    $(".deletecart").click(function(){
        id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        item_no = $(this).attr('data-itemNo');
        deletecart(id,item_no);
   });
```

But i think using the modal make's it more cool, i've try to get the index of `'#confirm-delete'` and use it to get the value of `".deletecart"` but the index is always -1, please anyone can help with this , thanks alot

I edit my question and post my code below is it

```
 <?php 
//print_r($carts);exit;
  if(isset($carts) && !empty($carts)){
        foreach ($carts as $key => $cart){
            $myurl = Yii::$app->UrlManager->createUrl(['/item','Id'=>$carts[$key]['slug'].'/'.$carts[$key]['product_id'],'itmNo'=>$carts[$key]['item_number']]);
            echo "<div class='col-md-12 invisible-divider-20'></div>";
            echo "<div class='col-md-12'>";
            echo "<div class='tb_logo_cart pull_left'><img src=".$img."Logo_4_png.png alt=logo></div>";
            echo "<div class='small-text-12 pull_left store_name_link'>Store:&nbsp;<a href=>".$carts[$key]['store_name']."</a></div>";
            echo "</div>";

            echo "<div class='col-md-12 cart_body'>";
                    echo "<div class='checkbox'>"
                         . "<label class='check_container pull_left'>"
                                . "<input type='checkbox'class='cart-checkbox' data-class='cart-ck-5'>"
                                . "<span class='checkmark'></span>"
                         . "</label>"
                       . "</div>";

                echo "<div class='row nopadding'>";
                        echo "<div class='cart_item_img col-md-3 nopadding'><a href=".$myurl." class='nopadding'><img src=".$profileimg.$carts[$key]['profile_img']. "></a></div>";
                        echo "<div class='col-md-4 cart_title'>";
                             echo "<a href=".$myurl.">".$carts[$key]['title']."</a>";
                             echo "<div class='cart-condition text-muted'>Condition: ";
                                    if($carts[$key]['product_condition'] == 0){
                                        echo 'Not specified'; //if no item condition for this product show not specified
                                     }elseif($carts[$key]['product_condition'] == 1){
                                         echo "New with tags";
                                     }elseif($carts[$key]['product_condition'] == 2){
                                         echo "New without tags";
                                     }elseif($carts[$key]['product_condition'] == 3){
                                         echo "New with defects";
                                     }else{
                                         echo "Used";
                                     }
                             echo "</div>";
                             echo "<div class='cart-sizes text-muted'>Size:".$carts[$key]['size']."</div>";
                             echo "<div class='cart-color text-muted'>Color:".$carts[$key]['color']."</div>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        $total_price =  round(($carts[$key]['quantity']*$carts[$key]['price']),2);  
                        echo "<div class='col-md-1 cart_action pull_right' title='delete item'><i data-toggle='modal' data-target='#confirm-delete' class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i></div>";
                        echo "<div class='col-md-2 cart_total_price pull_right'>";
                                echo "N:<span>".$total_price."</span>";
                                echo "<div class='cart-shipping'>Shipping: <b>FREE</b></div>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "<div class='col-md-1 cart_qtty pull_right nopadding'>";
                             echo "<span class='cart-qtt-control'>";
                                 echo "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus text-muted left-ctr' data-id=".$carts[$key]['id']." data-price=".$carts[$key]['price']."></i>";
                                 echo "<input type='text' value=".$carts[$key]['quantity'].">";
                                 echo "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus text-muted right-ctr' data-id=".$carts[$key]['id']." data-price=".$carts[$key]['price']."></i>";
                             echo "</span>";
                             echo "</div>";
                             echo "<div class='col-md-1  cart_unit_price pull_right'>N:<span>".$carts[$key]['price']."</span></div>";

                echo "</div>";            

            echo "</div>";

            echo "<div class='modal fade' id='confirm-delete' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>"
                    . "<div class='modal-dialog'>"
                       . "<div class='modal-content'>"
                            . "<div class='modal-header'>"
                                . " <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>×</button>"
                                . " <h4 class='modal-title' id='myModalLabel'>Confirm Delete</h4>"
                            . "</div>"

                            . "<div class='modal-body'>"
                                . " <p>You are about to delete an item.</p>"
                                 . "<p>Do you want to proceed?</p>"
                            . "</div>"

                            . "<div class='modal-footer'>"
                                . "<button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Cancel</button>"
                                . "<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-ok' data-id=".$carts[$key]['id']." data-itemNo=".$carts[$key]['item_number'].">Delete</button>"
                            . "</div>"
                    . "</div>"
                 . "</div>"
               . "</div>";

        }
    }
```

?>

```
function deletecart(id,item_no){
 var url = '{$url}'+'?itemNumber='+item_no+'&mode=remove&status=';
   $.ajax({
                url: '{$deletecartUrl}',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {id: id},
    success: function (data) {  
                if(data === 'success'){
                  window.location= url+data;
              }else{
                  window.location= url+data;
             }
           },
        error: function(jqXHR, errMsg) {
         // handle error
            console.log(errMsg);
        }
    });
   }


$('#confirm-delete').on('click','.btn-ok', '.deletecart', function(e) {
        var modalDiv = $(e.delegateTarget);
        id =  $(this).attr('data-id');
        item_no = $(this).attr('data-itemNo');
                    console.log(id); 
                    console.log(item_no); return;
        //deletecart(id,item_no);
        modalDiv.addClass('loading');
        setTimeout(function() {
            modalDiv.modal('hide').removeClass('loading');
        }, 1000)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What I generally do in these situations is inject the data- values to the modal html:

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-ok" data-id="..." data-itemNo="...">Delete</button>`

or even:

`<div class="modal fade" id="confirm-delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-id="..." data-itemNo="...">`

Then getting the values is onclick is trivial. Imo the best way to do this is to use a js templating system like Nunjucks. Dynamically generate the modal html via Nunjucks when the initial delete button is clicked (rather than harcoding the modal html on the page). Another option though is to use jquery/js to inject the data- values.

Comment: Thank for your help, i tried what you suggested but when i click on the delete button to get the data-value i keep getting the same value for all data, say data-id=11 but i have many data with different id which i can see from my page source, var id = $(this).data('id'); it only get the same id which is the id of the last data in the array, what i'm i doing wrong

Comment: @sam you'll need to post your code/edit your question, I can help without it

Comment: @ KayakinKoder  i've edited my question and posted my code kindly see if i can get any help from you, thanks